# Why does Safari iOS think that iPad Pro handles up to 5 touches?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari, touch

I made an experiment with `navigator.maxTouchPoints` and Safari on iOS returns `5` for my iPhone and also `5` for my iPad Pro 2018.

It seems right for the iPhone - my sixth touch gets unnoticed, in fact the sixth touch cancels all other touches.

But on my iPad, there are more touches being registered than `5`, actually I managed to make it up to `13` and I'm pretty sure that's not all. Just being curious here - why is `navigator.maxTouchPoints` wrong?

Here's my test:

```html
<div class="content">
    <div id="actual">0</div>
    <div>|</div>
    <div id="max"></div>
</div>
```

```js
document.getElementById('max').textContent = navigator.maxTouchPoints;

['touchstart', 'touchend'].forEach(eventName => {
    addEventListener(eventName, event => {
        document.getElementById('actual').textContent = event.touches.length;
    });
});
```

P.S. Please don't ask me how I managed to touch 13 spots. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: See the note 2 in [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents2/#extensions-to-the-navigator-interface).

Comment: Good find! Thanks.